# Amount counter works only on first product

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a problem with using javascript with SQL.
It looks like this that I have few items that appears on the screen, they appears from SQL database, and the code looks like shown. Bascially if I have more than one product that is shown on the website, only first one works as it should. Any solutions?

```js
let displayAddCounter = document.querySelector("#add_count_cart");
let displayRemoveCounter = document.querySelector("#remove_count_cart");
let displayCounter = document.querySelector("#amount_count_cart");

var x = 0;

displayAddCounter.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(x < 10){
    x++;
    displayCounter.innerHTML = x;
  } else {
    alert("If you want to buy more than 10, please contact our support! We will gladly help you :)")
  }
});

displayRemoveCounter.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(x == 0){
    displayCounter.innerHTML = x;
  } else {
    x--;
    displayCounter.innerHTML = x;
  }
  
});

let buttonCartAdd = document.getElementById("btn_add_to_cart");
let itemName = document.querySelector(".product_name");

buttonCartAdd.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(x == 0){
        alert("Please choose amount of items!");
    }
    else if(x > 0){
        alert("You added " + x + itemName.innerHTML + " to the cart!");
    }
  
});
```

```html
 <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <div class="product_card col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-4 box-shadow">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="product_name my-0 font-weight-light"> <?php echo $row["productName"]?> </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title"> </h2>
            <img class="pic" src="productsImages\<?php echo $row["productID"];?>.jpeg" height="150px" width="120px"></img>
            <br>
            <p>
            <?php echo $row["productPrice"];?> SEK
            </p>
            <div class="row amount_counter">
              <button id="remove_count_cart" type="button" class="col_amount btn btn-outline-secondary col-3 col"> - </button>
              <div id="amount_count_cart" class="btn col-6 col border-top border-bottom dark rounded h-75">
              0
              </div>
              <button id="add_count_cart" type="button" class="col_amount btn btn-outline-secondary col-3 col"> + </button>
              <button id="btn_add_to_cart" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success col-lg-8 col-md-12 col offset-lg-2"> Add <i type="button" class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `id` for all the HTML elements for each product; you should either use relative routes instead of `document.querySelector`, or have individual `id`s for each product

Comment: not "**or**" but "**must**" have unique id

Comment: They must have unique id if you care about following specs (Though admittedly you should), but as it's been discussed multiple times, in practice it probably won't matter as long as you know which ones are repeated, where they are, and how to treat it. 

If instead of having unique id's he uses, for example, [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), it will work (Assuming there are no more problems), even though it goes against the spec

Comment: It's not like there is a choice, you have to use the specs